# systemd: Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: 5m

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I am trying to get a simple systemd service to run on a timer unit. For some reason, systemd doesn't seem to like the way I am specifying time. The script worked when I used `minutely` or `daily` as the value for `OnCalendar`, but now I want to set it to 5 minutes and systemd gives an error:

```
/etc/systemd/system/backup.timer:7: Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: 5m
backup.timer: Timer unit lacks value setting. Refusing.
```

Thing is, according to [this page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.time.7), `minutes` should be an understood unit of time. They have `2hours` as an example timespan that should work there, so I don't understand why `5m` or `5minutes` is somehow invalid.

Here is my timer file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer unit for backup.service
Requires=backup.service

[Timer]
Unit=backup.service
OnCalendar=5m

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The other thing is, when I run `systemd-analyze timespan 5minutes` it does not return an error, and it seems to be able to parse the value correctly:

```
Original: 5minutes
      μs: 300000000
   Human: 5min
```

Comment: Looking for references, but I'm pretty sure `OnCalendar=` expects a time-stamp, not a time-span. For time-span, you probably want `OnActiveSec=` or  `OnBootSec=`.

Comment: That was it, thank you!

Comment: Great, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`5m` is a time-**span**.  `OnCalendar=` expects a time-**stamp**.

According to [systemd.time(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html), a time-stamp is a unique point in time, while a time-span is a duration.

If you want to keep `OnCalendar=`, then use a time-stamp like:

- `minutely`, `hourly`, `daily`
- `2012-11-23 11:12:13`
- `Mon,Fri *-01/2-01,03 *:30:45`

If you do want to use a duration, then try `OnActiveSec=` or `OnBootSec=` which takes a duration and adds it to the time the unit became activated or the system booted.  See [systemd.timer(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) for more options such as `OnUnitActiveSec=` (when the timer was last triggered)

> Defines realtime (i.e. wallclock) timers with calendar event expressions.

A calendar event expression is a "unique point in time".

Comment: This is a great answer thank you, especially for explaining why `daily` and `minutely` worked while the other values did not.